# Install linux from USB without bios support

Tags: boot, system-installation

I have an old PC where I want to install Debian from "smaller CD" (up to 40mb, rest will be downloaded). I have made a bootable usb from this Debian.

The problem is, my computer is so old that it (bios) doesn't support booting from USB.

1. **I have** some **debian CD** where I can run (rescue) shell from, but it's corrupted and I'm unable to install the whole Debian from it (fails on copying base system).
2. **I have** also **hiren's cd 14.0** which includes Parted Magic live linux with shell and other utilities
3. I am **not able to burn** any other CD/DVD.

**How can** I run shell from any of these CDs and then **boot usb to run installation from it?**

Comment: Get somebody to burn a CD for you? Anything else is just too much pain...

Comment: I don't know Debian, but in Fedora there is the option of doing an install from the net from the install screen. Perhaps you have enough working to try that. There is also a "install from hard disk" option, perhaps the USB drive is recognized as a "hard disk"?